# Cities FR formatter cases

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, formatting

I searching a function which can convert the input of user as new output with specific rules.

This rule is :

- First letter uppercase (e.g: **P**aris)
- If string contains two dashes (-) between each words, apply a uppercase on the first letter of second word (e.g: Saint-**E**tienne)
- If string contains a specific word like: `au`, `aux`, `et`, `sur`... between two dashes (-), apply a lowercase on the first letter of theses words (e.g: Saint-Etienne-**a**ux-Temples)
- If string contain a word with single quote like: `l'eveque`... between two dashes (-), apply a lowercase on the first letter and a uppercase on the letter just after single quote of the words (e.g: Parigné-**l'E**vèque).

This is too hard task for me, but I found this function which respect the first and second rule but not the third and fourth rule:

```
function ucwords(str,force) {
    str=force ? str.toLowerCase() : str;
    return str.replace(/(^([a-zA-Z\p{M}]))|([ -][a-zA-Z\p{M}])/g,
    function(firstLetter){
        return firstLetter.toUpperCase();
    });
}
```

1. Input: `paris` **--->** Output: `Paris`
2. Input: `saint-etienne` **--->** Output: `Saint-Etienne`
3. Input: `saint-etienne-aux-Temples` **--->** Output:
   `Saint-Etienne-aux-Temples`
4. Input: `parigné-l'eveque` **--->** Output: `Parigné-l'Eveque`

Can someone help me to add the last rules of this function?

Thank you

Comment: @HemanGandhi the program works fine for the rule 1 and rule 2. But no for the rule 3 and 4. Try to write : paris-l'eveque . The program have to convert the string like : Paris-l'Eveque (rule 3). Try also to write : paris-aux-anges, the program have to convert the string like : Paris-aux-Anges. (rule 4). thx

Comment: Vilela Pinto, yes, I undestood. I thought your numbered list was one of test cases. Sorry.

Comment: How many specific words are there for the third rule?

Comment: @The_Grits The list should be extensible because there are a lot of little words which compose the French cities and I haven't the count of all. Maybe build an array of words and increment it gradually ?

Comment: At this point I can confirm these words : 'des', 'aux', 'le', 'les', 'sur'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I came up with this using `split` and `join`. It seems to handle all the cases.

```
function myUC(str){
    var wds = str.split('-');
    var acc = [];

    var exclude = ["aux", "au","et", "sur", "des", "le", "les"];

    wds.forEach(function(wd){
        if(wd.length == 0)
            return;
        else if(exclude.includes(wd)){
            acc.push(wd);
        }else if(wd.indexOf("'") == 1){
            acc.push(wd[0].toLowerCase() + "'" + wd[2].toUpperCase() + wd.substr(3));
        }else{
            acc.push(wd[0].toUpperCase() + wd.substr(1));
        }
    });

    return acc.join('-');
}
```

I'm sorry, I don't know if regex can solve your problem.

Comment: thk's is almost perfect ! I use this program each keyup and keydown. So when I write this : paris- i have a "Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined" on the console. The function seems don't like the user's input . Is because there are no more letter after the 'dash' ?

Comment: Not really, I "hacked" your solution but I don't know if it's clean.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I edited the answer of @Heman Gandhi because his solution only works when the string is fully written.

In my case I want compute my string each time I write something (with keyboard). My hacked solution is :

```
field.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {

   myUc(field.val());
});

function myUC(str){
    var wds = str.split('-');
    var acc = [];

    var exclude = ["Aux","aux",
                    "Au","au",
                    "Et", "et",
                    "Sur","sur",
                    "Des","des",
                    "Le","le",
                    "Les","les"];

    wds.forEach(function(wd){

        if(wd.length == 0)
            acc.push(wd[0]);

        else if(exclude.includes(wd)){
            acc.push(wd.toLowerCase());

        } else if(wd.indexOf("'") == 1 && wd.length > 3) {

            acc.push(wd[0].toLowerCase() + "'" + wd[2].toUpperCase() + wd.substr(3));

        } else {

            acc.push(wd[0].toUpperCase() + wd.substr(1));                               
        }
    });

    return acc.join('-');
};
```

I don't like define twice the same word in exclude array but if I don't do this the function loop indefinitely through two conditions. If @Heman have a more cleaner solution this is welcome :)

Comment: Maybe `else if(exclude.some(function(e){e.toUpperCase() == wd.toUpperCase()})` and so on, so that `exclude` can have only the lower case values.